# How to pass parameters from SplashScreen to HomeScreen using react-navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation for routing between screens. Now, the scenario is I have used SwitchNavigator for authentication.

Example:

**SplashScreen**

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken? 'App' : 'Auth', { extraParams: value});
```

**LoginScreen / Home Screen**

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.extraParams
```

This returns only **routeName** and **key**. Please find the reference code that I am using.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  AsyncStorage,
  Button,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Please sign in',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Sign in!" onPress={this._signInAsync} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _signInAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', 'abc');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
  };
}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome to the app!',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Show me more of the app" onPress={this._showMoreApp} />
        <Button title="Actually, sign me out :)" onPress={this._signOutAsync} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _showMoreApp = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Other');
  };

  _signOutAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
  };
}

class OtherScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Lots of features here',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="I'm done, sign me out" onPress={this._signOutAsync} />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _signOutAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
  };
}

class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._bootstrapAsync();
  }

  // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
  _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
  };

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen });
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
));
```

Can anyone please help to get an appropriate solution to pass extra params from SplashScreen to HomeScreen or LoginScreen?

Comment: Don't put only external links, please add the code to your question

Comment: What kind of external links? Could you please show me a code?

Comment: I want to access extraParams in HomeScreen after app redirects from SplashScreen or SignInScreen

Comment: You just changed it, thanks! That is better!

Comment: Yeah!! Actually, I am using this code. I am unable to pass params on navigation.